# a function calculates time in 24 notation

Tags: c++

Is there a function that calculates the time in 24 notation? the time call is entered by the user to calculate the price of long-distance call, if the user input the time of his call at 1:30 p.m.?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int time , num_of_min ,ans;
    double cost;
    char day ,day2 ;

    cout<<"Please ,Enter the first two letters of the day you have made the call \n";
    cin >>day>>day2;
    cout<<"Please , Enter the time you have made the call in 24-Hour Time \n";
    cin>>time;
    cout<<"Please , Enter in minutes how long is the call\n";
    cin>>num_of_min;
    while(true)
    {
        if((time>=8  && time <=18&& time>=1 && time<=24)&& (((day=='m'||day=='M')&& (day2=='o'||day2=='O'))||((day=='t'|| day=='T')&&(day2=='u' || day2=='U'))|| ((day=='w'|| day=='W')&& (day2=='e'|| day2=='E')) || ((day=='f'|| day=='F')&& (day2=='r'|| day2=='R')) ||((day=='T' || day=='t')&& (day2=='h'|| day2=='H'))))
        {
            cost=0.40 * num_of_min;
        }
        else if (((time>=1  && time <8 ) ||( time>18 && time<=24))&& (((day=='m'||day=='M')&& (day2=='o'||day2=='O'))||((day=='t'|| day=='T')&&(day2=='u' || day2=='U'))||((day=='w'|| day=='W')&& (day2=='e'|| day2=='E'))||((day=='f'|| day=='F')&& (day2=='r'|| day2=='R')||((day=='T' || day=='t')&& (day2=='h'|| day2=='H')))))
        {
            cost=0.25 * num_of_min;

        }
        else if (( time>=1 && time<=24)&& (((day=='s' || day=='S')&&( day2=='a' || day2=='A'))||((day=='s' || day=='S')&& (day2=='u' || day2=='U'))))
        {
            cost=0.15 * num_of_min;
        }
        cout<<"\nthe cost of your call = " << cost <<"  "<<"dollars";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: can you tell me more

Comment: There's no standard library function that converts between 12- and 24-hour formats, if that's what you're asking. It's a fairly common exercise for students to implement one.

Comment: Simplify your expressions… For example with `(time>=8  && time <=18&& time>=1 && time<=24)`, **if time is between 8 and 18 then time is also between 1 and 24**. Simpler expressions are easier to understand.

Comment: In 24 hours format, hours is between **0 and 23 inclusively** (for example 00:15 for 15 minutes after midnight).

Comment: If the user enter invalid data, cost will be garbage on first iterations and will be previous iteration cost on subsequent iterations. And by the way all iterations will print the same cost as user inputs are outside the loop but then there is a `return` inside the loop so finally the loop is useless. **You should try your code first!**